# New Contact not listed

Tags: android

I used this code to add the contact:

```
    public static long addNewNameToContact(Context context, String name) {

    long rawContactId = 0;

     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

     values.put(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, name);

     Uri rawContactUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values); 
     rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri); 

    return rawContactId;
}
```

(I need to create a contact only with the name and then add phone and other data).

Can you help me?

Very thanks, 
Mateus

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create a raw contact specifying the account type and name. The account type and name can be any string. For instance accountType="com.mateus.app" and accountName="user":

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
values.put(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
Uri rawContactUri = getContentResolver().insert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, values);
long rawContactId = ContentUris.parseId(rawContactUri);
```

Then, you can set the display name with the raw contact ID that is returned above:

```
values.clear();
values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
values.put(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Mike Sullivan");
getContentResolver().insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: Right and if you want to find more examples check the SampleSyncAdapter: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

Comment: Hi! Data.CONTENT_URI doesn't exists... can you help again?